# Clear Android webview cache every 'n' number of days

Tags: android, html, caching, webview

I am working on an android webview app which is cache enabled. The web page I would be caching would have data updated periodically and I don't want users to look at same data everytime.

My idea is to write a code in my app that can clear the cache every 'n'  number of days.  One thought I had is to read when the cache was created and if it exceeded the period,  I want to clear it so my app creates it afresh.  I am open to any other thoughts as well.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: `AlarmManager` can perform an action every n days. Not sure what method allows you to clear the cache, though

Comment: I guess html has some tags from where we can enable caching or fetch new content if it is added.